# IntelliJ doesn't automatically break line

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm having issues with IntelliJ automatic `Reformat Code` on one specific line of code:

```
catch (MyException1 | MyException2 | MyException3 | MyException4 | MyException5 | MyException6 | MyException7 | MyException8 e) {
```

- I have set in `Editor -> Code Style` Hard wrap at 140
- In `Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces` everything is either `Chop down if Long` or `Wrap if long`

Now, the issue is that running `Code -> Reformat Code` doesn't break this line into 2 automatically (it should as it exceeds 140 characters). And what's worse, if I break it manually, then `Reformat Code` will bring it back to one line. As I have the `Line Length` inspection on, IntelliJ complains about this line.

This is the only line in the whole project where IntelliJ has this problem, all other expressions containing `+` or `||` etc. are correctly wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping or chopping down multi-catch types is not supported on IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 and below. IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 will support this. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178941